# javascript indexOf - exact match in a list / array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list

I decided to use javascript indexOf to determine if a value exists in a list / array. This was working for me untill I realised that I need to find an **exact** match in the list.

Here is my example code:

```
if (['eu', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW'].indexOf('fr') > -1) {
```

The above code will 'match' fr to fr-CA, which is a problem for me, as I must have an **exact match to fr** and not match to fr-CA.

I thought that this would be straight forward, but I have searched SO and google, and cannot find an answer to getting the exact match.

Comment: Wait, what, are you sure?

Comment: `['eu', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW'].indexOf('fr')` gives you `-1`

Comment: that's not possible and that's why you can't find anwser

Comment: Yes. I just realised. I need to get some sleep.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thats wrong, you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> `arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = 0])`
>
> `indexOf` compares `searchElement` to elements of the `Array` using strict
>   equality (the same method used by the `===`, or triple-equals, operator)

So `['eu', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW'].indexOf('fr')` returns `-1`.

Comment: OMG! You are correct. This is a prime example of why I cannot survive on 2 hours sleep a day. I am a dufus.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var match = ['eu', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW'].filter(function(item){
    return item === 'eu';
});

console.log(match); // an array of matches, only one item in this case
```

Though your could should work fine. Perhaps you missed something else?

http://jsfiddle.net/ydm7k6xm/

Comment: You've basically implemented `.indexOf()` behaviour right there :P

Comment: @Ja͢ck Hehe, well a more expensive version of it, performance-wise...

Comment: this one worked for me, indexOf() seems not to be checking for the exact string, but this one does.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method. It will stop search once the first match is found, or return false if nothing matches:

```js
var arr = ['eu', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW'];
var match = arr.some(function(el) {
    return el === 'zh-CN';
});

alert(match);
```

Or regular expressions can also be used. For example:

```js
var arr = ['eu', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW'];
var match = new RegExp('^' + arr.join('|') + '$').test('zh-CN');

alert(match);
```

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` when compare array value is equal to the same value in the array. then only it returns true otherwise it always returns false

if you want to be search substring in the array value use this below function. it search the substring in the array and returns the position in the array

```
function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}

var res = searchStringInArray('fr',['eu', 'fr-CA', 'lt', 'sv', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW']);

alert(res);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ds0c20ft/)